# Using tidyverse and pipes how do I assign fixed rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

Given this dataframe

```
X1          X2   
2001        NA
abc         10
def         12
xo          13
2002        NA
abc         10
efd         22
dd          23
2005        NA
a           30
```

All the years have NA in X2. My goal is to get this data frame to become

```
X1          X2        Date
abc         10        2001
def         12        2001
xo          13        2001
abc         10        2002
efd         22        2002
dd          23        2002
a           30        2005
```

That is, the years became their own column and the NA's have been dropped

What I tried

```
a = read_csv("given.csv")
a %>% mutate(Date = ifelse(is.na(X2), X1, NA))
```

This turns the first dataframe to

```
X1          X2      Date
2001        NA      2001
abc         10      NA
def         12      NA
xo          13      NA
2002        NA      2002
abc         10      NA
efd         22      NA
dd          23      NA
2005        NA      2005
a           30      NA
```

I'm not sure how to replace the NA of the date column into the upper value for each year. After that I think i can just drop_na and it will be like i would want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

a %>% 
  mutate(Date = na.locf(case_when(is.na(X2) ~ X1))) %>%
  na.omit
```

Output:

```
    X1 X2 Date
2  abc 10 2001
3  def 12 2001
4   xo 13 2001
6  abc 10 2002
7  efd 22 2002
8   dd 23 2002
10   a 30 2005
```

If you want to reset row numbers just use `filter(!is.na(X2))` instead of `na.omit`.

P.S. You can of course just load `tidyverse` and do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  mutate(Date = case_when(is.na(X2) ~ X1)) %>%
  fill(Date) %>%
  drop_na
```

.. however note that `fill` is quite slow compared to the `na.locf` function from `zoo`.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a grouping column based on the occurrence of numbers only elements (`\\d+`) in 'X1', get the cumulative sum, create the 'Date' as the `first` element of 'X1', `ungroup` and remove the NA rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
a %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(X1, '^\\d+$'))) %>% 
    mutate(Date = first(X1)) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-grp) %>%
    na.omit
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  X1       X2 Date 
#  <chr> <int> <chr>
#1 abc      10 2001 
#2 def      12 2001 
#3 xo       13 2001 
#4 abc      10 2002 
#5 efd      22 2002 
#6 dd       23 2002 
#7 a        30 2005
```

---

Or using `data.table` with `zoo`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
na.omit(setDT(a)[, Date := na.locf(fifelse(is.na(X2), X1, NA_character_))])
```

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(X1 = c("2001", "abc", "def", "xo", "2002", "abc", 
"efd", "dd", "2005", "a"), X2 = c(NA, 10L, 12L, 13L, NA, 10L, 
22L, 23L, NA, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```